# unquote [& args] on macro

Tags: macros, clojure

If I want to define a function that accepts an unknown number of args I can easily do something like this:

```
(defn foo
  [& args]
  args)
```

It returns a value of type `clojure.lang.ArraySeq` which contains the value given in the function.

In macro, using `~@` is unquote-splicing, which flattens the argument given:

```
(defmacro foo
  [bar & baz]
  `(println ~@baz))
```

If I use the macro like this:

```
(foo "foo" 1 2 3 4)
```

It will print out `1 2 3 4`. But, I want to get the args unflattened. Doing `~baz` (without `@`) gives me an exception. Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you `macroexpand-1` the version using `~baz`, the cause of the problem becomes apparent:

```
(macroexpand-1 '(foo "foo" 1 2 3 4)) ; NB. using ~baz in foo's body
;= (println (1 2 3 4))
;            ^
```

So here we're attempting to call `1` as a function. (NB. this call takes place and the exception is thrown at run time.)

The right way to fix this depends on what you want to achieve. For example, you could pour the rest arg into a vector and print that:

```
(defmacro foo [bar & baz]
  `(println ~(vec baz)))
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `macroexpand-1`

Answer (score 2):

A comment on Michał Marczyk's answer ...

You can also see what's happening by turning the macro into a function:

```
(defn foo [bar & baz]
  `(println ~@baz))

=> (foo "foo" 1 2 3 4)
(clojure.core/println (1 2 3 4))
```

Syntax quoting, unquoting, and unquote splicing still work. Aha! Macros differ from functions in how they are invoked, not in what they do.

Answer (score 1):

You can always do

```
(defmacro foo
  [bar & baz]
  `(println (list ~@baz)))
```

to construct a seq or

```
(defmacro foo
  [bar & baz]
  `(println [~@baz]))
```

to construct a vector.